# Running external .rmd files from a .rmd file - R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I want to run an external `.rmd` file(AKA rstudio notebook file) when I run a specific `.rmd` file. For example, the project X has `a.Rmd`, `b.Rmd`, and `c.Rmd` files. However, to run `c.Rmd` I need to run `a.Rmd` and `b.Rmd` first. Currently, each time I run `c.Rmd` I have to run `a.Rmd` and `b.Rmd` manually beforehand. Is there a codeline like when I run `c.Rmd`, it will automatically run `a.Rmd` and `b.Rmd`?, for example:

Inside `c.Rmd`:

```
execute(a.Rmd)
execute(b.Rmd)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the difference between an RStudio notebook file and any other R Markdown file, but this would work in the latter:

```
rmarkdown::render("a.Rmd")
rmarkdown::render("b.Rmd")
```